# How to stop background music with a switch button in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am working on an app in Swift, which has back ground music playing. The music is started inside the AppDelegate function:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
```

But I have a view controller called SettingsViewController which is where there is a switch that I want to be able to stop the back ground music.

How can I make the switch button stop the music?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a singleton like `SoundHelper.swift` to deal with all sounds. Create functions `startPlayingBGM()` and `stopPlayingBGM()` in this singleton class.
2. When the app launches, call function `SoundHelper.sharedInstance.startPlayingBGM()`.
3. In the switch function, just call the function as `SoundHelper.sharedInstance.stopPlayingBGM()`

If you are not familiar with swift singleton, google it, learn a little bit, it will be very useful. You can even find some Github examples of sound helper in swift, take a look at those codes.

If you don't want singleton, you can still create a global structure `Sound.swift` with all static variables in it.

```
struct Sound {
  static var isVolumeOn = true
  ...
  static func playSound() {
    //....
  }
  static func stopSound() {
    //....
  }
}
```

Then you can access all the static functions and variables from outside. For example, when app launches, call `Sound.playSound()`, and call `Sound.stopSound()` in your switch function.

Comment: I have created a singleton like you suggested. But I have come up on a different problem. I have made it so that the status of the switch is save, On or Off. But when the app is first installed it doesn't know if the switch is on or not. So the music does not play until you go switch the switch off and then on. Any suggestions?

Comment: the 2nd method has a `isVolumeOn = true` variable, you can use that.